# How to find AWS Local Path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, nuxt.js, cicd

I am deploying nuxt 3 project from bidbucket to AWS s3 bucket. I am following [this](https://gist.github.com/bgreater/07ee09f6f95ac8d51de0afc89779ff80) link for nuxt deployment `bidbucket to aws s3`

I need to know how can I find the AWS local path.

Kindly please help me to find that relevent details

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The AWS_local path mentioned in that pipe is nothing but the folder which you want to deploy to s3. I have done this 100's of times.

For example, I am going to deploy a change of my glue jobs to the location where the glue job points in S3. Then the folder name in my repo is "glue_jobs_code",  I want it to be deployed to S3 so I just mention the folder name there like below.

```
 LOCAL_PATH: "glue_jobs_code"
```

EDIT : It should be the name of your local directory simply!

Best!
Sai Teja

Comment: Thank you for your revert. I just tried using my bucket name in a local path but still it returns the error `LOCAL_PATH must be a directory

Comment: Yes local directory path that you want to deploy. May be my answer is confusing, I will edit it.

Comment: Hello, one question Are you sure we need to give the only bucket name here? because I have set but still it does not work.

Even though I have tried to set the clon directory path but it will push all my directory code maybe it should only upload dist folder data am i correct?

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya I have given a complete example step below, Please proceed with that in your example.

Comment: I have fixed the local path issue but now occurred another issue that `dist folder not found` even though I have added the ls command in the step of the pipeline and it shows dist folder there

Comment: Please share your step and screenshot of your ls result?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the local folder in your working directory that want to deploy into S3 as AWA_LOCAL_PATH.

Further if you don't want to deploy the whole repo but only few files from different src folders, the way we do is before the S3 deploy pipe I will use script section on the same step to crate a new directory on the fly and copy the files that wanted to deploy into that.

Now all I have to do is give that folder name to S3 deploy pipe as AWS_LOCAL_PATH.

```
- step: deploy-glue-script-modules
    name: "Deploying glue script modules"
    deployment: staging
    script:
      - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:1.1.0
        variables:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $DE_AWS_KEY
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET 
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION 
          S3_BUCKET: code-$ENV/project-name/modules
          LOCAL_PATH: "modules"
```

Best!
Makanist

Comment: Thanks for the replay! I have write just dist folder on path but it return error on deployment steps that `dist folder not exist`

Comment: You have to give local relevant path of that folder. Otherwise pipe can't find it. If still you are facing issue please share a screenshot of your folder structure to review.

Comment: @Kishan Bhensadadiya - Do you still have this problem? If solved please close the issue and accept the answer, otherwise, share more details as requested.

Comment: issue is occurred please check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76540147/bitbucket-pipelines-dist-folder-not-exist-on-deployment-step?noredirect=1#comment135017982_76540147