# Bitbucket pipelines dist folder not exist on deployment step

Tags: deployment, nuxt.js, bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I am deploying nuxt 3 project using Bitbucket. my issue is when the pipeline runs 2nd step after 1st is completed successfully it returns the error

> ✖ dist directory doesn't exist.

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```js
# This is a sample build configuration for JavaScript.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/14UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: node:19.3.0
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 1024 
      
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Build and Test
          services:
            - docker
          size: 2x 
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm set audit false
            - npm install
            - export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096
            - npm run generate
            - ls
          artifacts:
            - dist/**
      - step:
          name: Deploy
          deployment: production
          script:
            - ls
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:1.2.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION
                S3_BUCKET: $AWS_BUCKET_NAME
                LOCAL_PATH: "dist"
                ACL: "public-read"
                CACHE_CONTROL: "max-age=30672000"
```

Here, in the first step I have write `ls` and in that step dist folder exists and showing on the list but in the 2nd step when I check ls log then seems dist folder not showing there

1nd steps ls screenshot

[image]

2nd steps ls screenshot

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: What does it show to be in the artifacts after the test step?

Comment: @James Z Its blank!

Comment: @Randommm was the one asking that question

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya If the artifact is empty then there is no content in dist so it doesn't make the folder

Comment: Yes @Randommm that's the issue artifacts are not received on 2nd step on dist if I set pages or any other folder instead of dist it's working fine!

Comment: what if you run `ls dist`, does it actually have anything inside of it?

Comment: @Randommm No it doesn't have anything

Comment: Then there will be artifact to create, thus dist won't be added

Comment: I have set `pages` directory on `LOCAL_PATH` and it's working perfectly and the dist and pages directory are on root.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy only once folder at a time with S3 deploy. If you need dist also to be deployed into S3. May be you should have pages and dist under a folder lets say "deploy_folder" Then deploy it to you s3 location. That way you could deploy dist and pages folder in a  single step.

In case you need to deploy both folders at two different S3 locations, then you must have 2 separate s3 deploy steps.

Let me  know if this solution helps.

Regards,
Makanist